# How to re-open a Compact Disk

Tags: gnome, cd, ubuntu-mate

I blanked a Compact Disk and now it has 2 KB of data and doesn't burn anything. Is there a way to ***re-open*** the disc again ?

I tried to re-open the session with wodim

```
sudo wodim /dev/cdrw blank=unclose
wodim: No write mode specified.
wodim: Assuming -tao mode.
wodim: Future versions of wodim may have different drive dependent defaults.
Device was not specified. Trying to find an appropriate drive...
Detected CD-R drive: /dev/cdrw
Using /dev/cdrom of unknown capabilities
Device type    : Removable CD-ROM
Version        : 0
Response Format: 2
Capabilities   : 
Vendor_info    : 'TSSTcorp'
Identification : 'CDDVDW SE-208DB '
Revision       : 'MF00'
Device seems to be: Generic mmc2 DVD-R/DVD-RW.
Using generic SCSI-3/mmc   CD-R/CD-RW driver (mmc_cdr).
Driver flags   : MMC-3 SWABAUDIO BURNFREE 
Supported modes: TAO PACKET SAO SAO/R96P SAO/R96R RAW/R16 RAW/R96P RAW/R96R
Errno: 5 (Input/output error), start/stop unit scsi sendcmd: cmd timeout after 40.658 (40) s
CDB:  1B 00 00 00 01 00
cmd finished after 40.658s timeout 40s
wodim: WARNING: Total disk size unknown. Data may not fit on disk.
Speed set to 1764 KB/s
Starting to write CD/DVD at speed  10.0 in real TAO mode for single session.
Last chance to quit, starting real write in    0 seconds. Operation starts.
Errno: 5 (Input/output error), send opc scsi sendcmd: cmd timeout after 60.872 (60) s
CDB:  54 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
cmd finished after 60.872s timeout 60s
wodim: OPC failed.
```

This is the screen-shot from *Gnome Disks*

[image: Gnome Disks]

Comment: If the medium is already blank then it is normal that i cannot be blanked
again. The size of 2 KB seems bogus. A blank CD-RW is empty.
If you want it formatted with UDF filesystem, try this shell command:
cdrwtool -d /dev/sr0 -q

Comment: @ThomasSchmitt I don't find cdrwtool anywhere, system or repos.

Comment: [It's in the `udftools` package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/udftools/filelist) in the Universe repository.

Comment: I did troubleshooting with an Audio CD and the device surely has problems.